# Calculating Time Complexity of a Method Call within a Method call

Tags: java, algorithm, time, complexity-theory

https://i.stack.imgur.com/buYvQ.jpg

So I've been tasked with creating methods in java that do basic operations (add, subtract, multiply) with HugeIntegers (which are arrays that house digits in their indexes, eg. 1111 would be [1,1,1,1]).

After writing our code, we are asked to analyze the time complexity of it (ie. Big theta complexity classes) and I'm having a little bit of trouble analyzing a part of my code (see link).

I know that the x1.add(diff) will give me big theta (n) where n is the number of digits of the HugeInteger, and compareTo(x2) will also give me big theta (n). The contents inside the while loop are also big theta (n).
Now, is the total time complexity of this piece of code big theta of (n^3) or would it be n^2? I am having a bit of trouble with the while loop condition, as I am unsure if the n's should add or multiply. I know that whatever that result is will be multiplied by the n inside of the while loop, though.

Any help is very, very appreciated. I've been on stuck on this for the better part of a week.

Comment: Next time just put your code in your question.  It's easier than clicking a link to look at a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition of the loop will be run one per loop iteration.  The contents of the loop will also be run once per loop iteration.  So you can add those.  Then, of course, multiply by the number of times the loop runs.  If the condition is (n) and the loop body is (n) then together they are still (n).  If the loop runs (n) times, then the total is (n^2).